# Laravel Event Broadcast not being picked up laravel-echo-server

Tags: javascript, laravel, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

I'm attempting to use laravel-echo-server (socket.io) I'm getting a roadblock where the client-side doesn't appear to be getting any broadcasted events.

Everything seems to be connected fine and socket.io server is reporting that it's connecting and authorising the user however when I broadcast a message nothing seems to happen. The event is appearing on Laravel Horizon but otherwise, nothing happens. Here is my code:

server.js to run the laravel-echo-server:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const env = process.env;

require('laravel-echo-server').run({
    authHost: env.APP_URL,
    devMode: env.APP_DEBUG,
    database: "redis",
    databaseConfig: {
        redis: {
            host: env.REDIS_HOST_PUBLIC,
            port: env.REDIS_PORT,
        }
    }
});
```

My channel in channel.php

```
Broadcast::channel('message.pushed', function () {
    return true;
});
```

My event:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MessagePushed implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->message = "My New Message";
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('message.pushed');
    }
}
```

My event listener within app.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
window.io = require('socket.io-client');


if (typeof io !== 'undefined') {
    var token = $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    window.Echo = new Echo({
        auth       : {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        },
        broadcaster: 'socket.io',
        host       : window.location.hostname + ':6001',
    });
}



function listenForBroadcast() {
    Echo.private('message.pushed')
    .listen('MessagePushed', (e) => {
        console.log(e)
        console.log("Listened")
    });
}

listenForBroadcast();
```

Lastly the route sending the message:

```
Route::get('/event-test', function () {
    broadcast(new App\Events\MessagePushed());
});
```

I am not quite sure where i have gone wrong or why nothing is being picked up by the client.

While looking in laravel-echo-server the command line is echoing:

```
Channel: laravel_database_private-message.pushed
Event: App\Events\MessagePushed
```

Answer (score 0):

In you browser you need to listen on Channel as shown by redis and also listen to the event as shown by redis, so changing your listenForBroadcast() method may help.
In the code, Channel name changed from message.pushed to laravel_database_private-message.pushed and Event name changed from MessagePushed to .App\Events\MessagePushed ( Do not miss dot prefix to App )

```
function listenForBroadcast() {        
    Echo.private('laravel_database_private-message.pushed')         
    .listen('.App\\Events\\MessagePushed', (e) => { 
        console.log(e)
        console.log("Listened")
    });
}
```

I tried this solution based on the solution given in the following link and it worked for me 
[laravel Echo does not listen to channel and events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066633/laravel-echo-does-not-listen-to-channel-and-events?rq=1)